# What does \x in PHP PCRE mean?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> After `\x`, up to two hexadecimal digits are read (letters can be in
>   upper or lower case). In UTF-8 mode, `\x{...}` is allowed, where the
>   contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is
>   interpreted as a UTF-8 character whose code number is the given
>   hexadecimal number. **The original hexadecimal escape sequence, `\xhh`,
>   matches a two-byte UTF-8 character if the value is greater than 127.**

So what does this mean?

The code point of "ä" is E4 while the UTF-8 representation is C3A4, but neiter of those matches:

```
$t = 'ä'; // same as "\xC3\xA4";

preg_match('/\\xC3A4/u', $t); // doesn't match
preg_match('/\\x00E4/u', $t); // doesn't match
```

With the curly braces it does match when I give the code point:

```
preg_match('/\\x{00E4}/u', $t); // matches
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that manual page badly needs re-wording: UTF-8 is an encoding into bytes of Unicode characters (code points), but it mentions "a UTF-8 character whose code number is..." and "a two-byte UTF-8 character", neither of which makes any sense. Either it is recognising a Unicode code point, or a UTF-8 byte sequence; I'm not at all sure which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is a way to specify a character by value:

- `\xAB` specifies a code-point in the range 0-FF.
- `\x{ABCD}` specifies a code-point in the range 0-FFFF.

The indicated wording from the manual is bit confusing, perhaps in an attempt to be precise. Character values 128-255 (and some) are *encoded* as 2-bytes in UTF-8. Thus, *a unicode regular expression will match 7-bit clean ASCII but will not match different encodings/codepages (i.e. [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) that utilize values in said range*. The manual is, in a roundabout way, saying that a unicode regular expression is only suitable to be used with correctly encoded input. However;

It doesn't mean that `\xABCD` is *parsed* as `\x{ABCD}` (one character). It is parsed as `\xAB` (one character) and *then* `CD` (two characters)<sup>1</sup>. The braces address this parsing ambiguity issue:

> After *\x, up to two* hexadecimal digits are read .. In UTF-8 mode, *\x{...} is allowed* ..

Some other languages use `\u` instead of `\x` for the longer form.

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider that this matches:

> preg_match('/\xC3A4/u', "\xC3" . "A4");